# Is it right to use spring DI without interface

Tags: java, spring, interface, dependency-injection

I am using spring dependency injection,where i can inject object dependency through some external xml file.

My question is :

**Is it fine to use spring DI without using interfaces?**

Because with DI,we want to achieve one thing :

If a class is being replaced by some other class having same methods but different definitions,then we don't need to make any change in code where this class is being referenced.

This is fine if i am using interface as interface can point any class which is implementing this interface but if i am directly injecting class object through DI then there is no meaning of DI because in this case if class get replaced,i have to change my code also where it is being referenced.

Please let me correct if something is wrong.

Let's say i have

```
Class Datasource{

    String url;
    String user;
    String database;

}
```

Now i am using it without DI as

```
Class Abc{

     Datasource datasource = new Datasource();
}
```

what's the problem in this and what are the benefits i can get if i use DI.

Is getting singleton object only goal of DI?

Comment: That isn't the thing you want to achieve with Dependency Injection. You want to externalize the control of configuring the related objct (i.e. the service using a repository). DI has nothing to do with being able to replace a dependency. Dependeny Injection can and will work regardless of the fact if you use interfaces or not.

Comment: We do not mention interfaces in XMLs but classes. In real time applications, classes are rarely replaced or exchanged with some other classes. And DI is not "If a class is being re...."

Comment: @M.Deinum if DI is not "if a class..." then what is the benefit of DI,why should i externalize the control?

Comment: Because you might wnat to reuse an object (singleton) or provide a proxy of the actual object. You don;t get all that if you instantiate objects inside the other object. However that isn't the main benefit you don't want to construct objects all over the place. Imagine the need for a datasource, you probably want to configure it once and have other classes use it, you don't want each class to setup a `DataSource`.

Comment: @M.Deinum not getting your point,please see my update in question

Comment: A `DataSource` is a heavy object (I known it is an interface with multiple implemenations but still). If you have 150 services and each would construct a new instance that would be killing your database. You would want to be able to reuse a single instance. Next to that for testing you might want to use a in-memory one and in reallife you might want to retrieve something from JNDI. If you would hardcode the latter in your code testing would become a lot harder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dependency Injection isn't about interfaces or classes or enums or... It is about [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Imagine the following class.

```
public class PersonService {

    private PersonRepository repository = new PersonRepository();
}
```

Apparently there is nothing wrong with this. However what if `PersonRepository` needs other dependencies, what if it takes another complex object as construct argument. Suddenly the `PersonService` is burdend with the logic on how to construct an object and all of its dependencies. Whereas it only wants to use the object.

```
public class PersonService {

    private PersonRepository repository;

    public PersonService() {
         InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
         repository = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/repositories/person");
    }
}
```

The code above is tied to JNDI, how are you going to test it (easily) of course you can construct your own Mock JNDI service and pre configure that with a constructed or mocked repository but that is quite cumbersome.

```
 public class PersonService {

      private final PersonRepository repository;
      public PersonService(PersonRepository repository) {
          this.repository=repository;
      }
 }
```

The above makes basically everything possible, there is no burder on the `PersonService` on how to construct the `PersonRepository` it is just handed one, where it comes from it doesn't matter. Is it the actual class or a (class-based) proxy, is doesn't care.

Hence dependency injection, you want to hand the `PersonRepository` to use to the `PersonService` it shouldn't matter to it where it comes from, how it is constructed or if it is a proxy to an actual object. It just needs a `PersonRepository`.

Comment: thanks for your answer,it makes some sense,where object creation is a little bit complex task then DI should be used,but i have seen many projects where object creation is straightforward like new Abc(),still people use DI to inject Abc.

Comment: It isn't about simplicity it is about responsibilities... It isn't the responsibility of the `PersonService` to construct the referenced objects it needs. Just give them to the object.